# How to show existence of a hyperplane in $\mathbb{C}^n$ which misses finitely many points

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $E\subset\mathbb{C}^n$ be a finite subset and $0\notin E$. Then show that there exists a hyperplane of $\mathbb{C}^n$ which passes through the origin and does not contain any point of $E$.

I just have a heuristic argument: If a hyperplane intersects any of the point in $E$ then we can rotate it by small angle such that it misses every point of $E$, since E is discrete.

But I am not able to make this argument precise.

Is there any easy way to see this result?

Comment: It suffices to project the points down to $\Bbb C^2$, and find a line not containing any of the projected points.

Comment: True. How to proceed after that?

Comment: @Tanuj The line in $\Bbb C^2$ "unprojects" back to a hyperplane in $\Bbb C^n$, and since the line didn't contain any of the projections of the points, the hyperplane doesn't contain any of the points.

Comment: Yeah, I got that form Omnomnomnom's comment. But what after that?

Comment: If you mean how to find the line, it can be constructed in the way you described in the question, since now you have an explicit _slope_ which you can rotate.

Comment: @Arthur: Aren't you forgetting that we're being asked to find a hyperplane _through the origin_?

Comment: But we still need to prove the $n=2$ case, right? I mean, we need a complex line not intersecting any of the points in the finite set.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I see, I forgot that the projection of points in $E$ might end up at the origin in $\Bbb C^2$. So just projecting alone is not a true reduction of the problem to $\Bbb C^2$. You have to be clever about what projection you use.

Comment: Notably, finding a projection that doesn't map any points to $0$ amounts to finding an $n-2$ dimensional space (the kernel of the projection) that doesn't contain any of the points.  So, it would seem that we have a nice setup for an inductive argument.

Comment: @Tanju if we have $n = 2$ with $0 \notin E$, then it suffices to take a line at every possible slope through the origin.  Note that no two lines contain the same non-zero point.  So, if every line hits a point in $E$, then we must have infinitely many points in $E$, which we don't.

Comment: Potentially interesting argument along the lines of Dominik's approach: take $E = \{e_1,\dots,e_m\}$, and define the linear map $f: \Bbb C^n \to \Bbb C^m$ by $f(v) = [\langle v,e_i \rangle ]_{i=1}^m$.  We need to show that the image of $f$ contains a point whose coordinates are all non-zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every Hyperplane through the origin can be written as $\{x \in \mathbb{C}^n \mid \langle v, x \rangle = 0\}$, where $v \ne 0$ is a normal vector of the hyperplane. We can use this fact to prove the assertion via induction.

Let $E = \{e_1, \ldots, e_m\}$. If $m = 1$, the assertion holds trivially. For $m > 1$ we can find (by our induction hypothesis) a vector $v \ne 0$ so that $\langle v, e_i\rangle \ne 0$ holds for all $1 \le i < m$. Now note that for any $t \in \mathbb{R}$ we have

$$\begin{align*}
\langle v + t e_m, e_m \rangle &= \langle v, e_m \rangle + t \langle e_m, e_m
\rangle \\
\langle v + t e_m, e_i \rangle &= \langle v, e_i \rangle + t \langle e_m, e_i\rangle \qquad \text{for}\ 1 \le i < m
\end{align*}$$

It is easy to see that there is a $t = t_0$ so that all of these terms are nonzero (just note that each term is zero for at most one value of $t$). But this means the Hyperplane $\{x \in \mathbb{C}^n \mid \langle v + t_0e_m, x\rangle = 0\}$ does not contain any element from $e$.

Comment: so by this process this result can be extended to countable sets as well. But if we take a countable dense set, then we know that the result is not true.

Comment: No, this process only works for finite sets $E$. However, the result does hold for any countable set $E$ that does not contain the zero vector. To see this, observe that for any $e \in E$ the set $M_e = \{x \mid \langle x, e\rangle = 0\}$ is a hyperplane and therefore a Lebesgue-Nullset. But this means that $M = \bigcup \limits_{e \in E} M_e$ is a nullset and in turn its complement is nonempty. Every vector from $M^c$ now satisfies $\langle x, e\rangle \ne 0$ for all $e \in E$.

Comment: But you are using induction in your proof. So it is true for a countable set.

Comment: Also, if the result is true for any countable set not containing the origin,  then what is the hyperplane in $\Bbb{C}^2$ that misses the rational points, i.e., $\{ p+iq, r+is\} \setminus \{0\}$ where $p,q,r,s \in \Bbb{Q}$

Comment: Induction does not work like this. I can prove via induction that every finite set is finite. Does this also mean that every countable set is finite? Clearly not. For your second example, consider e.g. the Hyperplane that is orthogonal to $(\sqrt{2}, 1)$.